# How do I get the Gradle "cpp" plugin to use gcc instead of g++ for a C project?

Tags: gcc, gradle, build.gradle

The Gradle "cpp" plugin tries to use g++ to build my C project and the build fails because C isn't C++. I've tried using the "-x c" and "-std=gnu90" options of g++ to no avail.

How do I override the "cpp" plugin's use of g++ and have it use gcc instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that version 1.7 of Gradle doesn't support C source-files but that (incubating) version 1.9 does. Downloading the nightly build solved the problem.